# How can I trigger an extension in selenium

Tags: python, c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use the `chrome.tabCapture` API in my extension using selenium and it requires the `activeTab` permission to be granted.

Its usually granted by clicking on the extension icon or by hotkey, but I cannot click the icon and the triggering the hotkeys using `Actions.Perform()` doesn't trigger the `chrome.commands` callback.

I used to use the command line argument `--whitelisted-extension-id`, but with the latest updates. Its just crashing the browser instantly.

I heard there may be a way to do it with the `<all_urls>` permission, but I haven't seen a way to make that work if anyone has a working example.